# /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error when remove & install broken packages

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I tried to remove unstable `openoffice` and reinstall `libreoffice` however I accidently removed directory of `openoffice` under `/opt` before I purged it. Now I cannot clean the broken package, and cannot remove/install `libreoffice` too. `apt-get -f install` doesn't work with error:

```
....
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a4.2.7-0ubuntu2_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

and I followed [How to fix a broken package](http://blog.adimian.com/2014/10/how-to-fix-a-broken-ubuntu-package-installation-here-slapd/) by removing the packages manually via `dpkg` but it did not remove it clean. Same problems hold still.

And I have unmet dependencies which I cannot clean or move up:

```
dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-calc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libreoffice-java-common
 libreoffice-sdbc-hsqldb
 libreoffice-core
 python3-uno
 libreoffice-math
 libreoffice-impress
 libreoffice-writer
 libreoffice-base-core
 libreoffice-gnome
 libreoffice-base
 libreoffice-sdbc-firebird
 libreoffice-report-builder-bin
 libreoffice-pdfimport
 libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer
 libreoffice-gtk
 libreoffice-base-drivers
 libreoffice-draw
 libreoffice-calc
```

Basically they depend on a package named `libreoffice-common`, but I have no idea how to purge or install it.

---

Update:

Followed instructions from [mchid](https://askubuntu.com/a/599936/191410) and `sudo apt-get install ...` reports (actually they did the same things as `apt-get install libreoffice`) terminated with:

```
Selecting previously unselected package xfonts-mathml.
Preparing to unpack .../xfonts-mathml_6ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking xfonts-mathml (6ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.2-0ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-icon-theme (3.10.0-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for fontconfig (2.11.0-0ubuntu4.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a4.2.7-0ubuntu2_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

---

What all I know now, is that it seems I purged everything with `libreoffice` and `openoffice`. Using command:

```
sudo apt-get purge libreoffice*
sudo apt-get purge openoffice*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get clean
sudo dpkg --configure -a #double check, reports nothing
sudo dpkg -L libreoffice
sudo dpkg -L openoffice
```

all of them shows they have been cleanly removed, however, I just couldn't install `libreoffice`, with a single line of `/usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`.

Comment: @mchid `dpkg -L openoffice` shows the location.

Comment: maybe you mean `dpkg -l | grep openoffice`?

Comment: did you manually download libreoffice package? Try to redownload it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [@mchid](https://askubuntu.com/a/599936/191410) first, for trying to help. However in this case I have to remove openoffice clean, and sadly it's broken therefore there is no way to purge it in a normal way.

How to make this work? Fix the broken package first. So:

- Step 1. check if any packages broken.

  ```
  sudo dpkg -l | grep openoffice # check if any packages remained, and what are they
  sudo dpkg -l | grep libreoffice
  ```

Since I did have unclear package remove, I have to purge it:

- Step 2. prepare to install.

  ```
  sudo apt-get purge openoffice* libreoffice*
  ```

Repeat step 1 and 2 until `dpkg -l | grep office` command reports nothing more. Then there should be clean.

- Step 3. install again.

We can move up to fix openoffice, (cannot be purged by step 1 and 2) following: [official guide to install openoffice on linux](http://www.openoffice.org/download/common/instructions.html#linux) and there're lots of instructions on internet too.

- Step 4. purge it clean.

Once we are done, run: `sudo apt-get -f install`. There shouldn't be any problem. And we can remove the package again, since we now have `apt-get` working normally:

```
sudo apt-get purge openoffice*
sudo dpkg -l | grep openoffice # shouldn't report anything, since we cleanly removed it
```

- Step 5. install libreoffice.

and we can install libreoffice again:

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

Finally my libreoffice worked.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are running [regular ubuntu](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-ZvkSoewYu9A/VEkmmDz-GwI/AAAAAAAAKi0/YY7IyUhmo4A/s1600/Ubuntu-utopic-2.jpg) and not [ubuntu-gnome](http://ubuntugnome.org/screenshots/), run the following commands to fix the problem:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get purge openoffice* libreoffice* python3-uno
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-java-common libreoffice-sdbc-hsqldb libreoffice-core python3-uno libreoffice-math libreoffice-impress libreoffice-writer libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-base libreoffice-sdbc-firebird libreoffice-report-builder-bin libreoffice-pdfimport libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer libreoffice-gtk libreoffice-base-drivers libreoffice-draw libreoffice-calc
```

Comment: I think `apt-get purge` triggers the error anyway, since `apt-get` runs on the top of `dpkg`. I'm trying to remove packages manually, forcing by `sudo dpkg --force-all -P` to purge. And it seems works. Wait a moment to know.

Comment: @knh190 well then, why don't you give it a try and thank me afterwards :)

Comment: Yeah, it purges the packages clean but cannot install them correctly. `apt-get` reports poor information to know what's going wrong.

Comment: @knh190 please post the error from `sudo apt-get install`

Comment: I made up the information.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22183/discussion-between-knh190-and-mchid).