# Installing LibreOffice in 16.04

Tags: dependencies, libreoffice

I need help with installing LibreOffice. I previously had it OK but an upgrade would not work as said 'unmet dependencies'. I have purged it and it is all gone.
When I try to re install from software Centre I get the following error message:

```
Package dependencies cannot be resolved
libreoffice: Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial2) but 1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial2 is to be installed.
```

Any ideas on how to get the missing stuff please?

Comment: Do the following `sudo apt install -f`, then `sudo apt update` and try again

Comment: What version of  LibreOffice are you trying to install?

Comment: You uninstalled one package of the dozen that make up LibreOffice. You must uninstall them all.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

`sudo apt-get -f install`

`-f` stands to "fix broken". It will attempt to correct broken dependencies.
After this run the following :

`sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Then again

`sudo apt-get -f install`

This generally works for most cases. For more details you can look at this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa).

Comment: Thank you. I tried the above and I now get the following error message-libreoffice: Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial2) but 1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial2 is to be installed

Comment: Did you try the above link? and have a look here " https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2355016&page=2 " and this "https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial2 " or you can manually download from the previous link.

Comment: I have worked through the link. When I get to sudo apt-get-f install I get an error message- Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a5.4.2~rc2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo2_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/599926/usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-when-remove-install-broken-packages : This should do the work , just go for accepted answer.